# Remove styles from TinyMCE bullet points

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm using ***TinyMCE*** html editor in my cakephp (2.5) project. When I use *bullet points* in this editor, it's shows underline with every bullet point. I used default TinyMCE settings with cakephp.

I attached sample screen shot. Is anyone has an idea to prevent this, thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's web developer tools to investigate the styles being applied?

Comment: It 's not TinyMCE's fault; it doesn't happen when I try with TinyMCE on my website. Check your stylesheets.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja - yes I did, but it didn't come from my style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that it would do that by default.  I assume there is some other setting or CSS that's throwing it off, but either way, if you want to override it, you can use your own CSS for the TinyMCE content:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone in the future. I've realised that tinyMCE copies the style of `<p>` to the bullets possibly in an attempt to make them look uniform.